# Smoothly Rotate Object Towards Target Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate my player vehicle into the target object direction/side.
Though the following image, I have tried to explain my point in better way:

[image]

I want to rotate my below tank object towards another tank object so that it can point into that direction.

I have written this code for this purpose but it is not working:

```
IEnumerator DoRotationAtTargetDirection(Transform opponentPlayer)
{
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    do
    {
        Debug.Log("do rotation");
        Vector3 targetDirection = opponentPlayer.position - transform.position;
        targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);
        Quaternion nextRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.localRotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime);
        transform.localRotation = nextRotation;
        yield return null;

    } while (Quaternion.Angle(transform.localRotation, targetRotation) < 0.01f);
}
```

I just want to smoothly rotate and stop towards a target object.
Please share your suggestion regarding this.

**EDIT:**

This is updated code that still not working, tank object gets stuck in rotaion as like above image:

```
 IEnumerator DoRotationAtTargetDirection(Transform opponentPlayer)
{
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    do
    {
        Debug.Log("do rotation");

        Vector3 targetDirection = (opponentPlayer.position - transform.position).normalized;
        targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime);

        yield return null;

    } while (Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, targetRotation) < 0.01f);
}
```

Tank object forward direction:

[image]

Comment: Rather than doing complete rotation towards target object - it just gets stopped as like my above image.

Comment: This has become a very high quality question thanks to your edits!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Time.deltaTime` is an inappropriate lerp parameter. Instead, define a `float rotationSpeed` and use `rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime` as the `maxDegreesDelta` argument to [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html).

Also, using `LookRotation` in that way will give you a world-space rotation. So you should assign your result to `transform.rotation` instead of `transform.localRotation`.

Altogether, these changes might look like this:

```
public float rotationSpeed;

IEnumerator DoRotationAtTargetDirection(Transform opponentPlayer)
{
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    do
    {
        Debug.Log("do rotation");
        Vector3 targetDirection = opponentPlayer.position - transform.position;
        targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);
        Quaternion nextRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
                transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.rotation = nextRotation;
        yield return null;

    } while (Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, targetRotation) > 0.01f);
}
```

Comment: Check my updated code that still not working and I have changed localRotation to normal rotation - also if we multiply with Time.deltaTime or not that does not matter because I have complete enumerator for this purpose only though it will take longer time

Comment: using only `Time.deltaTime` is the same as having `rotationSpeed = 1f` so that's fine :) I will keep looking into why the problem is still not fixed

Comment: @Siddharth I realized that the `while` statement should be while it's *greater than* `0.01f`. Let me know if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Oh man, you are the genius :) Thank you so much.... - from above just remove local rotation it maybe not work though I have not tested.

Comment: 1. RotateTowards never overshoots the target. If you use `Lerp` with `Time.deltaTime`and the device lags for some reason so that you have a frame with a really large `Time.deltaTime > 1`,  then it will output a result where it may rotate beyond where it should go. And if `Time.deltaTime > 2` then it would be even further away from the target than where it was before. In theory you could use `Lerp(a,b,Mathf.Min(1f,Time.deltaTime))`;

Comment: @Siddharth It is good practice to always use the `..Towards` methods whenever you have contiguous cumulative actions based on deltas. `Mathf` contains for primite data types like `int` and `float`. There are also versions in `Vector2` and `Vector3`, and in `Quaternion`.