# Is there a way to rotate towards an object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a cube object with many duplicates in different positions. When I am standing next to one of those objects and press a key, my camera object (which rotates my player) should be able to rotate towards that said object so that the camera is "facing" the cube.

However when I use transform.Rotate, I can't get it to stop at a certain point so it just rotates 360 degrees on a loop, and I have tried Quaternion.RotateTowards with Quaternion.Euler but that rotates my camera to a set degrees, so if I have the degrees set to (0, 45f, 0), it will move 45 degrees in whichever direction I turn, so even if I am facing the cube as I enter the trigger, it will turn me 45 degrees in the opposite direction when it should not turn me at all.

```
// Version 1
Vector3 turn = new Vector3(0, 180f, 0);
float rotateSpeed = 1.5f;

// Version 2
float turnAmount = 90f;
float turnSpeed = 50f;

void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Cube")
    {
        nextToCube = !nextToCube;
    }    
}

void Update()
{
    if (nextToCube == true)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.V))
        {
            // transform.Rotate(turn * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime); // version 1
            // transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation,
                   Quaternion.Euler(0, -turnAmount, 0), turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime); // version 2
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I am not using a "transform target" because I have too many cubes so I would have to continuously add new game objects to my inspector.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smoothly Rotate Object Towards Target Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57809196/smoothly-rotate-object-towards-target-object)

Comment: In that solution, it has "Transform opponentPlayer" in the IEnumerator which means that it can only be used for 1 object at a time right? What if I have multiples of the same object? That's my main problem here is trying to find a workaround having many different transforms

Comment: well but you only rotate towards one object at a time right? I think your question is a bit unclear / you have to first understand what your actual individual problems are and then find solutions to those

Comment: Yeah I only rotate towards one object a time. However during that same runtime, I might decide to rotate towards another five of the same duplicate objects (one object at a time) which all have different starting positions/rotations

Comment: so I think your question should rather not be how to rotate towards an object .. link above already provides that ... it should rather be how to switch out the target according to the interactions of the user with your scene which there are many possible solutions for: e.g. use trigger, go by closeness etc

Comment: For instance you already go by trigger (should btw be `void OnTriggerEnter(Colider col)`) but only set a fixed rotation .. why not rather store the actual object you collided with `col` and then use its information to rotate towards it ... aka use it as the target in the above mentioned rotate towards target routine

Comment: I will give that a try. I was just experimenting with the code in the link provided above and was having major screen shake but will see how I go with using 'col' instead

Comment: @thehelaeper67 if something shakes it might indicate that two concurrent things try to manipulate the object to two different positions at the "same" time

Comment: Yeah I was testing the Quaternion.LookRotation, RotateTowards, etc, all separately but found no issue with them. I commented out a bunch of my camera code and that didn't solve it, so it is weird that it still shakes like crazy and causes massive lag.